# Why I have value in payload and in store I get null? redux/toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Main problem: null in store /redux devtools / but value in action.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwcRV.png)

my rankSlice

```
const initialState = {
  rank: [],
};

export const rankSlice = createSlice({
  name: "rank",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    rankAdd: (state, { payload }: PayloadActionInterface) => {
     const item  = state.rank.find((as) =>as.id === payload.id) 
     if (item) {
      return
     }
     else {
      state.rank.push({
        id: payload.id,
        updatedRankingMovie: payload.updatedRankingMovie
      })
    }
    },
 },
});




export const { rankAdd, rankRemove } = rankSlice.actions;

export default rankSlice.reducer;


interface PayloadActionInterface {
  id: number,
  rank: number
}
```

I guess that problem must be in slice, so I copied my code to check out.

Comment: This is impossible, can you try `console.log(payload.updatedRankingMovie)` inside the action's else block.

Comment: I followed your advice and it reach out  that ```      const item  = state.rank.find((as) =>as.id === payload.id) 
 ``` caused an error. Now I need to write new statement to have only on rank to each id.